# How to stylize a Xamarin.Forms iOS app when Android uses built in Material Design

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, material-design

There are many resources that show how to use Material Design as the default in Xamarin.Forms Android (ex https://blog.xamarin.com/material-design-for-your-xamarin-forms-android-apps/).

My question is, how would I add style to the iOS side without messing up the Material Design style. Do I have to use the OnPlatform functionality all over the place to just use the style on iOS or is there some more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think you need to manage differently for ios as now there is a option of material design in both android and ios provided by Microsoft you can implement it by adding `Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material`from nuget Manager in your android and IOS project respectively

after that for android add `FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);` in your MainActivity.cs file
and for IOS add `FormsMaterial.Init();` in your AppDeligate.cs file

you are ready to use Material design in your xamarin project use `Visual="Material"` for the control you need it in material design you can also assign this property to you content page if you need all your controls in material design